Next.js Project Deployment Issue on Vercel: Error Calling API
I've encountered an issue while working with a Next.js project using Supastarter. I've built the project and now I'm attempting to deploy it to the Vercel platform. I've used commands like vercel build and vercel deploy directly from my local machine. After the deployment, the pages are accessible, but I'm encountering errors when calling the API. The error message is as follows:
Error: Failed to load native binding
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@node-rs+argon2@1.8.1/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js:359:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at /opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11508
    at Function.Qt (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11878)
    at Q.e.<computed>.K._load (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11478)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at mod.require (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28) {
  page: '/api/auth.user',
  [cause]: [
    Error: Cannot find module './argon2.linux-x64-gnu.node'
    Require stack:
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@node-rs+argon2@1.8.1/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js
    - /var/task/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/[trpc]/route.js
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
    - /var/task/apps/web/___next_launcher.cjs
    - /opt/rust/nodejs.js
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
        at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:55:36
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
        at /opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11508
        at Function.Qt (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11878)
        at Q.e.<computed>.K._load (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11478)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
        at mod.require (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
        at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
        at requireNative (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@node-rs+argon2@1.8.1/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js:211:16) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [Array]
    },
    Error: Cannot find module '@node-rs/argon2-linux-x64-gnu'
    Require stack:
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@node-rs+argon2@1.8.1/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js
    - /var/task/apps/web/.next/server/app/api/[trpc]/route.js
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
    - /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js
    - /var/task/apps/web/___next_launcher.cjs
    - /opt/rust/nodejs.js
        at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
        at /var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:55:36
        at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
        at /opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11508
        at Function.Qt (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11878)
        at Q.e.<computed>.K._load (/opt/rust/nodejs.js:1:11478)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
        at mod.require (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.2.2_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0__react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:65:28)
        at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
        at requireNative (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@node-rs+argon2@1.8.1/node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js:216:16) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [Array]
    }
  ]
}

Could you please help me understand what's going wrong? I'm a Java engineer and not very familiar with this area, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Additionally, I suspect it might be related to the fact that my Mac has an ARM chip, causing the packaged build to be in ARM architecture. Could this be a factor?
